# How to replace a part of a string using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How do we go about doing the the following :

From the below string :

```
"datetime": "date(2018-10-10)"
"datetime": "date(2018-10-11)"
"datetime": "date(2019-01-11)"
"datetime": "date(2018-02-15)"
```

To:

```
"datetime": date("2018-10-10")
"datetime": date("2018-10-11")
"datetime": date("2019-01-11")
"datetime": date("2018-02-15")
```

Comment: No regex needed if you can just replace `" :"` with `" :` and and `)"` with `)`

Comment: @Capricorn is correct. I didn't realize you needed the quotes moved inside the parenthesis so my Regex answer will only get you partly there. Just do 2 find and replaces like Cap. said but add your double quotes. (1) Replace `"date(` with `date("` and (2) Replace `)"` with `")`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I did not realize the double quotes inside the parenthesis... The answer below will only strip off the quotes before and after the value of the json - not add double quotes inside the parenthesis. Instead, I posted a solution in the question comments recommending 2 find/replaces that will get to the desired output.

Give this a shot: `(?<=": )"|"(?=\n)|"$` Replaced with nothing / blank. Make sure to have the Regular Expression radio button selected under the Search Mode section in N++.

Explanation: `(?<=": )"|"(?=\n)|"$`

- `(?<=": )"` - Positive Look behind. Matches some pattern after an occurrence of the pattern inside the parenthesis. In this case, matches a double quote (") after a double quote, colon, and space (": ). This will grad the first quote of the line to remove before the value.
- `|` - Logical OR
- `"(?=\n)` - Positive Look ahead. Same as positive look behind, but looks after the pattern instead of before. In this case, matches a double quote that has a new line after it. This will catch all second double quotes to remove after the value.
- `|` - Logical OR
- `"$` - $ represents End of String. Since the final key, value pair of your list has no new line, the final quote would be missed from the Find/Replace. This will catch that very last double quote if it is the last character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following search and replace.  I tested this on Notepad++ v7.5.9

Search

```
"date\((.*?)\)"
```

Replace

```
date\(\"$1\"\)
```